# Upload cordova app to the Apple store with Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I noticed that Cordova is not compatible with the latest version of Xcode 10. To test the app I use this command:

```
cordova run ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
```

and it works all correctly. I would like to know if it is possible to load applications built with the old Xcode system on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Using XCode legacy build system works completely fine when uploading to the AppStore. I still maintain an ionic 1 project that way.

Also, might I suggest checking out the release notes on the new build system which might answer some of your questions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10